# Gitlab Runner and docker/docker-compose passing stored gitlab variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, nuxtjs

I have stored variables in My Gitlab project
I would like to pass this variables so when i build the nuxtjs app all the vars should be available like Google API keys Firebase credentials

[image]

These are my files:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:12.13.0-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/project-name
WORKDIR /usr/src/project-name

RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add git

COPY . /usr/src/project-name/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV PORT=3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

`Docker-compose`

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  nuxt:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
  - deploy

deployFrontend:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - deploy
  tags:
    - deploy
  script:
    - sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build --no-cache
    - sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
  when: manual
```

Comment: As these are environment variables, you just need to follow this [doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).

Answer (score 1):

You should pass Vars to the Docker build in .gitlab-ci.yml
and catch them in Dockerfile:

(for example I take two Vars of your list)

#### Dockerfile

---

```
FROM node:12.13.0-alpine

ARG FIREBASE_API_KEY
ENV FIREBASE_API_KEY=$FIREBASE_API_KEY
ARG FIREBASE_API_ID
ENV FIREBASE_API_ID=$FIREBASE_API_ID
...
...
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

---

#### .gitlab-ci.yml

---

```
- sudo export FIREBASE_API_KEY=$FIREBASE_API_KEY
- sudo export FIREBASE_API_ID=$FIREBASE_API_ID

- sudo docker build --build-arg FIREBASE_API_KEY --build-arg FIREBASE_API_ID -t NAME_OF_IMAGE -f path_to_Dockerfile .

- sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
# in docker-compose.yml use NAME_OF_IMAGE you built above
```

---